# Possible to create a UITableView that appears from the corner of a View Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I would like to model a table view after one found in the Todoist app (see below), is it possible to do this without and additional framework? If so how would I go about doing this?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a view controller with a `UITableView` and present it as `UIPopoverPresentationController`

```
let vc = UIViewController()

vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)

let popUp = vc.popoverPresentationController

popUp?.permittedArrowDirections = .up

popUp?.delegate = self

popUp?.sourceView = sender as! UIView  // here set the frame of the button that the arrow points to when popup is shown

present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

//

Inside the vc that you presents the popup make it implements the delegate `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` and write this method

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

Comment: That Works, but how would I have the arrow point to the center of a UI Button? Currently it points to [the top left corner:](https://imgur.com/a/oM6Y9Kp)